# Google Maps Places search html gives blank page

Tags: maps

I have created a page exactly as instructed - in fact copied directly from working Google maps page and I get a blank page.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Just created exactly the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add path to CSS file. Problem solved.

```
<link href="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
```